# PS3 remote not working after shutting off PS3 during restore

Tags: ps3

I accidentally shut off my PS3 when it was restoring and now my remote control won't work. Please help me.

Comment: Also the remote control came with the console I don't have the instructions for the ps3 anymore and it doesn't seam to have a reset button

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the official PS3 Blu-ray Remote, you can find the manuals for the two models that were made here:

https://www.playstation.com/en-us/support/manuals/ps3/

Scroll down to the Blu-ray™ Disc Remote Control header and the manual should show you how to set that back up.

The summary of the manual is that you need to set the bluetooth connection for the remote.

Turn on the PS3.
From the home menu, select Settings > Accessory Settings > Register BD Remote Control.  Press X.
Follow the instructions.

The manual has additional notes about this process.

Comment: It would be a better response if you would write a resume or what is in the link in case the link dies